# Complex "Flask"-SQLAlchemy query involving many tables

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 5 Tables:

User, Project, Dg, Ds and R.

Project has 3 privacy modes: private, public, project

What I need is as follows:

- all R of the DGs in a Project where Project.mode is public
- all R that belong to a User's DGs in that Project if Project.mode=private
- all R that belong to all other users' DGs in the same Project if Project.mode= project

The relationships are:

1 n User Project

1 n Project Dg

1 n User Dg

1 n Dg Ds

1 n Ds R

They can be multiple queries or just one. I would appreciate If someone would help, or give some resource that can help. I have looked at other similar questions but I am new to this subject and can't extrapolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

Dg2 = aliased(Dg)
# project-wide visible R
result1 = db.session.query(
    R, Ds.name).join(
    Ds).join(
    Dg).join(
    Project).filter(
        Project.acces_rights == 'project').join(
    Dg2).filter(
        Dg2.user_id == user_id)

# personal R
result2 = db.session.query(
    R, Ds.name).join(
    Ds).join(
    Dg).filter(
        Dg.user_id == user_id).join(
    Project).filter(
        Project.acces_rights == 'own'
    )

# all publicly visible reading points
result3 = db.session.query(
    R, Ds.name).join(
    Ds).join(
    Dg).join(
    Project).filter(
        Project.acces_rights == 'public')

results = result1.union(result2).union(result3)
```